# How to programmatically set parameters for EntityDataSource and DetailsView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, parameters, detailsview, entitydatasource

Im stumped!

What is the best way to programmatically set a selecting parameter for the `EntityDataSource` control?

Specifically, I want to use the Page.User.ProviderUserKey to get a record in a custom User Details table I have, for a DetailsView.

I've seen code using the `asp:ControlParameter` to pull a value from a control, but that almost seems like a hack for my situation.  I don't want an extra control just to set the parameter value.

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If creating a custom parameter type feels like too much work, you can programatically add a basic parameter as follows:

```
Parameter parameter = new Parameter("MyParam", TypeCode.String,
    Page.User.ProviderUserKey);
MyDataSource.SelectParameters.Add(parameter);
```

Something like this should give you what you need.

Comment: This is only giving the Parameter object a default value of ProviderUserKey

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own custom Parameter:

```
<my:CustomParameter Name="MyParam" />
```

The details of how to implement a custom parameter can be found on [Fredrik Normén's Blog](http://fredrik.nsquared2.com/viewpost.aspx?PostID=355). Using a custom parameter is as simple as using any of the built-in parameter types, but a quick example can be found on [ScottGu's Blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/01/23/436276.aspx).

The simplest implementation would look something like this:

```
public class CustomParameter : Parameter
{
    protected override object Evaluate(HttpContext context, Control control)
    {
        // This is where you would grab and return
        // the Page.User.ProviderUserKey value
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```