# How to Set a Parameter for WhereParameters in EntityDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an EntityDataSource and I need set WHERE to a Local Variable Type: GUID.

My problem is I am not able to send my local variable Guid to EntityDataSource for a WHERE OPERATION.

I also tried to to use a ControlParameter`<asp:ControlParameter Name="UserId" />` and have a Label with Text property on my Guid converted in String. But does not work.

Any idea how to solve teh matter

```
   <asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSourceListAuthors" runat="server" 
        AutoGenerateWhereClause="True" 
        ConnectionString="name=CmsConnectionStringEntityDataModel" 
        DefaultContainerName="CmsConnectionStringEntityDataModel" 
        EnableFlattening="False" EntitySetName="CmsAuthors" Where="" 
        EntityTypeFilter="" Select="">
        <WhereParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="UserId" />
        </WhereParameters>
    </asp:EntityDataSource>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution yo my problem:

- Adding a CUSTOM PARAMETER of type Object

Useful resources:

http://www.leftslipper.com/ShowFaq.aspx?FaqId=11

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/01/23/436276.aspx

[How to programmatically set parameters for EntityDataSource and DetailsView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053979/how-to-programmatically-set-parameters-for-entitydatasource-and-detailsview)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc294876%28v=Expression.40%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295043%28v=Expression.40%29.aspx

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/11/26/tip-trick-how-to-register-user-controls-and-custom-controls-in-web-config.aspx

My code now

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSourceListAuthors" runat="server" 
        AutoGenerateWhereClause="True" 
        ConnectionString="name=CmsConnectionStringEntityDataModel" 
        DefaultContainerName="CmsConnectionStringEntityDataModel" 
        EnableFlattening="False" EntitySetName="CmsAuthors" Where="" 
        EntityTypeFilter="" Select="">
        <WhereParameters>
            <cmsParameter:CustomParameter Name="UserId" />
        </WhereParameters>
    </asp:EntityDataSource>
```

---

New Class Added:

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

using System.Web.Security;

namespace WebProject.Core.Utilities
{
    public class CustomParameter : Parameter
    {
        protected override object Evaluate(HttpContext context, Control control)
        {
            MembershipUser currentUser = Membership.GetUser();
            return currentUser.ProviderUserKey;
        }
    }
}
```